# Equal space after li of unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've removed dot(.) after the `<li>` of `<ol>` and gave '|' after the number.

I've achieved it by using below code:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol li::before {
    content: counter(item) " ";
    counter-increment: item;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-right: 2.5px solid rgba(37, 194, 240, 0.8);
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

But the space after the numbers are not equal.

I need uniform spacing after the numbers.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

```css
ol{counter-reset: item;columns: 2;}
ol li{display:block;margin-bottom:10px;}
ol li::before {
 content: counter(item) " ";
 counter-increment: item;
 padding-right: 15px;
 border-right: 2.5px solid rgba(37, 194, 240, 0.8);
 margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>My abc</li>
<li>LiveColor</li>
<li>LiveFood</li>
<li>Ola</li>
<li>Uber</li>
<li>Good Chat</li>
<li>Food Panda</li>
<li>Domino'd</li>
<li>Clickfood</li>
<li>Smartyo</li>
<li>Tide</li>
<li>Webseries</li>
<li>GoPro</li>
<li>Liveshow</li>
</ol>
```

In addition to it, the font-family is such a way that all the numbers have different spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a set width (say 3em)...and align the text to the right.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  columns: 2;
}

ol li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(item) " ";
  counter-increment: item;
  padding-right: 15px;
  border-right: 2.5px solid rgba(37, 194, 240, 0.8);
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>My abc</li>
  <li>LiveColor</li>
  <li>LiveFood</li>
  <li>Ola</li>
  <li>Uber</li>
  <li>Good Chat</li>
  <li>Food Panda</li>
  <li>Domino'd</li>
  <li>Clickfood</li>
  <li>Smartyo</li>
  <li>Tide</li>
  <li>Webseries</li>
  <li>GoPro</li>
  <li>Liveshow</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: it worked, but when there are more texts in li, which will tend to go in two lines, will not show properly. Next line should start from the same position from the previous line.

Comment: Please @Paulie_D can you assist me?

Comment: I've found the solution using text-indent:-70px; to the li.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a table layout without the need of setting a fixed width and it will work whataver the numbers you will be using.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  columns: 2;
}

ol li {
  display: table-row;
}

ol li::before {
  display:table-cell;
  /*text-align:right; uncomment this if you want to align to the right  */
  content: counter(item) " ";
  counter-increment: item 99;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  /* we use background instead of border */
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(37, 194, 240, 0.8),rgba(37, 194, 240, 0.8)) 
     right 15px top 0/ /* right=padding right*/
     2.5px calc(100% - 10px) /* width=2.5px height=100% - padding bottom */
     no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>My abc</li>
  <li>LiveColor</li>
  <li>LiveFood</li>
  <li>Ola</li>
  <li>Uber</li>
  <li>Good Chat</li>
  <li>Food Panda</li>
  <li>Domino'd</li>
  <li>Clickfood</li>
  <li>Smartyo</li>
  <li>Tide</li>
  <li>Webseries</li>
  <li>GoPro</li>
  <li>Liveshow</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these css codes..

```
ol{counter-reset: item;columns: 2;}
ol li{display:block;margin-bottom:10px;position: relative;padding-left: 40px;}
ol li::before {
    content: counter(item) " ";
    counter-increment: item;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
ol li::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(37, 194, 240, 0.8);
    height: 100%;
    width: 2px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but when there are more texts in li, which will tend to go in two lines, will not show properly. Next line should start from the same position from the previous line. Please can you assist me?

Comment: Tried it but it is not working.
I've found the solution using text-indent:-70px;
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target only certain items, you could use the :nth-of-type selector:

```
ol li:nth-of-type(n+10)::before {

}
```