# Alignment of a list with a custom style when the number of digits changes

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a numbered list with the items enumerated as [1],[2], and so forth. Furthermore, I need to use counters. The snippet below generates the basic result I am interested in.

Question: Is it possible to align the list numbers so that the single-digit numbers e.g. [9] right-align with the two-digit numbers, e.g., [10]?

```css
body {
    counter-reset: cnt;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}


ol > li:before {
    content: "["counter(cnt)"]";
}

ol > li {
    counter-increment: cnt +1;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li> Item 1 </li>
<li> Item 2 </li>
<li> Item 3 </li>
<li> Item 4 </li>
<li> Item 5 </li>
<li> Item 6 </li>
<li> Item 7 </li>
<li> Item 9 </li>
<li> Item 9 </li>
<li> Item 10 </li>
<li> Item 11 </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225066/8620333

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I can think of is the `text-align-last: justify` css property. This would require you to change things up a bit, but also a bound so that it doesn't expand too far and looks awkward. You can take a look at my example below. But I'm no CSS expert and I think that Safari doesn't support this feature.

```css
body {
    counter-reset: cnt;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
}


ol > li > p:before {
    content: "["counter(cnt)"]";
}

ol > li {
    counter-increment: cnt +1;
}

ol > li > p {
    text-align-last: justify;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li><p> Item 1</p></li>
<li><p> Item 2</p></li>
<li><p> Item 3</p></li>
<li><p> Item 4</p></li>
<li><p> Item 5</p></li>
<li><p> Item 6</p></li>
<li><p> Item 7</p></li>
<li><p> Item 8</p></li>
<li><p> Item 9</p></li>
<li><p> Item 10</p></li>
<li><p> Item 11</p></li>
</ol>
```